# Restrict admin in Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

How would I restrict admin access in an Azure B2C tenant?

Azure B2C does not have admin units. If an admin signs in to the portal, it would seem that with 'user admin' rights they can alter accounts across the directory. Can this be restricted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible within the Azure Portal experience. You would need to build a bespoke webapp to restrict the cohort of customer accounts they can alter via custom business logic.

Answer (score 0):

See [Default user permissions -Restrict user's default permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions#restrict-member-users-default-permissions) and use the `Users` -> `User Settings` tab in B2C to limit `guest` and `member` access.